# Git: creating a new repo from existing repo's subfolder and keeping them in sync

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I currently have the following repository structure

```
Repository A
  - Folder 1
  - Folder 2
```

I need to take out the Folder 1 and create another repository like the following

```
Repository B
 - Folder 1
```

But there will be active development on both A and B's folder 1 for the time being until such a time where we do a cutoff. So the need is to be able to keep them in sync such that whenever a PR is merged into the develop branch of Repository A, the same changes can be merged to Repository B if they belong to Folder 1.

My git knowledge is limited so my first question is this a feasible task and if so how to go about setting up Repository B and the corresponding merge mechanism. I have seen an example of splitting a subdirectory into a repo here - https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository

But how do I keep them both in sync once they are created. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to handle this is to continue to work in the current repo with Folder 1 & 2. When you are ready, simply delete Folder 2 from the main repo.

Otherwise:

**Step 1**: Create new repo from another repo's subfolder

- The link you provided appears to have enough info to assist you in creating your new repo.

**Step 2**: Keep new repo in sync with old repo.

- It appears that the syncing of two repos can be accomplished with GitHub Actions.
- If you have GitHub actions available to you, [check out the github-sync repository](https://github.com/repo-sync/github-sync) which demos how to sync branches between repos.
- It's unclear if GitHub actions will be able to differentiate changes to Folder 1 specifically. You may need to keep Folder 2 in the second/new repo until you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I dont think I have github actions available to me. Any other way to keep them synced. I am ok with keeping folder 2 in repo B, just need to sync changes from A to B once there's a merge in develop branch of A